# Sequences: convergent, limit and diverse

Tags: real-analysis

A function defined f: $\mathbb{R}_+\rightarrow\mathbb{R} $ by: $ f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{18}{x}}$

1) Show that $f'$ has one minimum/maximum, define $f'$s monotony conditions and sketch $f$.

Now let $a>0\in \mathbb R$ and define the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^\infty $ by:

$x_0=a \ \ \ and \ \ \ x_{n+1}=f(x_n) \ \ \ , \ \ \ n\geq 1$

2) Show that $x_n\geq 3$ for all $n\geq 1$

3) Show that the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is decreasing.

4) Show that the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is convergent and find the limit.

I have done 1) and found that $f'(x)=0$ has the solution $x=3$. I am having trouble with 2-4.

2) I know that $f(3)=3$, that means $x_0+1=3$. Does that mean that given that the sequence is defined by $n=0$ that we know that if it were to be defined by $n=1$ it would equal 3 and is that the proof?

3 and 4) I'm uncertain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $f(x) \ge f(3) = 3$ for all $x > 0$. Hence $x_{n+1} = f(x_{n}) \ge 3$ for $n \ge 0$.

Note that $f(x)^2 \le  x^2$ for all $x \ge 3$, hence $3 \le f(x) \le x$ for all $x \ge 3$. Hence $x_{n+1} = f(x_n) \le x_n$ for all $n \ge 1$.

A non increasing sequence that is bounded below has a limit, call it $\hat{x}$
and since $f$ is continuous, we have $\hat{x} = f(\hat{x})$, or $\hat{x}^2 = f(\hat{x})^2$ from which we obtain the only real solution $\hat{x} = 3$.

Answer (score 1):

For 2), solve the equation
$$\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{3} + \frac{18}{x}} \geq 3$$
You should obtain the solution $x \geq -6$. Since $x_0 > 0$, $f(x_0) \geq 3$, thus 2) follows by induction.

To solve 3), solve the equation
$$\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{3} + \frac{18}{x}} \leq x$$
You should obtain the solution $x \geq 3$. Since $x_1 \geq 3$, you can show by induction that $x_{n+1} \leq x_n$ for all $n \geq 1$.

For 4), there's a general fact that if a sequence is decreasing (resp. increasing) and bounded from below (resp. above), then it converges. Once you know that the sequence converges, you are justified in letting $n \to \infty$ on both sides of
$$x_{n+1} = \sqrt{\frac{x_n^2}{3} + \frac{18}{x_n}}.$$
to conclude that
$$L = \sqrt{\frac{L^2}{3} + \frac{18}{L}},$$
where $L = \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$. Solving the equation gives $L = 3$.